# Google App Engine: An error occurred processing file '': Unauthorized. Aborting

Tags: google-app-engine, authentication, unauthorized

When I try to deploy my application, I get this error: ERROR appcfg.py:2149 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized. Aborting.

I provide my login and password correctly but I am not able to deploy my application.

Any solution?